# Mounting Nginx Ingress Certificates in Ingress Controller Pods as in Memory rather than K8s Secrets

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

As part of compliance efforts seems like we need to use the Ingress Certificates directly being mounted in Memory , using emptyDir with `medium:Memory` ,but I am not able to find any examples in Nginx Ingress Controller repo or otherwise on how to do so .
If any one has done this before , please provide some insights .

Answer (score 1):

I had never done this. Just tried and all worked fine. I had to put the certs manually though. I mean,I created a debian pod and installed everything manually. I don't know how are you going to do that part so it will be elegant.

Anyways, this is the yaml that worked for me with self signed certs for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx-https
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - image: debian
    name: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/nginx/certs
      name: certs
    tty: true
  volumes:
  - name: certs
    emptyDir:
      medium: "Memory"
```

And the request

```
curl -vvv https://service -k
...
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=www.example.com; O=example organization
*  start date: Jan 18 15:48:22 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 18 15:48:22 2022 GMT
*  issuer: O=domain Inc.; CN=example.com
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.31.62
> User-Agent: curl/7.59.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.14.2
< Date: Mon, 18 Jan 2021 15:52:41 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 612
...
```

Comment: Can you please be more verbose in the answer , where did you create the certs are they lying in namespace ?
from the yaml you provided it is not clear .
Thanks !